# C# MVC HTML5 Canvas Data

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, html5-canvas

I have some x and y positions in a database table, that go to make up a design for a window.

What I would like to do is draw this onto a HTML5 canvas in my app, but I'm not sure what the best way is to pass data out of my database into the canvas object (I'm not really a JavaScript/web guy).

It will just be drawing lines, that i can do but I'm not sure the best way to get the data into the canvas so I can draw it.

Comment: Please provide more details and possibly some code examples so we can get on the same page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A quick fiddle page for you, maybe this can get you started.
http://dotnetfiddle.net/D3OqTy

I recommend read some html5 canvas tutorial

- http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/

Comment: I never thought about just putting the data into the model and looping over it, i think that should do the trick. Thanks!